# How to change the last IP digits on Linux command line

Tags: linux, networking

I'm trying to change the last digits of the IP address that I stored as a variable:

```
ip=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2} | awk '{print $1}')
```

The output would be `192.168.0.1`, but what I'm trying to do is to set the variable with a different last octet such as `192.168.0.2`

Comment: `ifconfig eth0 | awk '/\<inet\>/ {gsub(/\.1/,".2"); print $2}'`... Or use bash for the substitution: `printf "%s\n" "${ip%.*}.2"`

Answer (score 0):

This `nextip()` shell function prints the next possible IP address by altering the last digit.

```
#!/bin/sh

nextip() {
        d=${1##*.}
        while true; do
                d=$(( (d+1) & 255 ))
                case $d in
                        0|255) ;;
                        *) break
                esac
        done
        echo ${1%.*}.$d
}

nextip 192.168.0.1
nextip 192.168.0.254
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.1
```

You can use it with the command substitution:

```
ip1=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')
ip2=$(nextip $ip1)
```